# Java Iterate Over Collection, will not work

Tags: java

I am currently working on a Java project,

below are my attempts at coding so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * This class models a zoo. It allows a single animal to be added to the zoo, a
 * batch of animals to be "imported" by reading data from a text file and for all
 * the animals to be listed in a terminal window.  It also ensures that all animals
 * in the zoo have a unique identifier.
 *
 * @author Jacov
 * @version Version 1, 01 August 2014
 */

public class MyZoo
{
   // zoo identifier
   private String zooId;
   // a number used in generating a unique identifier for the next animal to be added to the zoo
   private int nextAnimalIdNumber;
   // zstorage for the Animal objects
   private TreeMap<String, Animal> animals;

   /**
    * Create an "empty" zoo.
    *
    * @param zooId an identifier for the zoo, at least three characters long.
    */
   public MyZoo(String zooId)
   {
      this.zooId = zooId.trim().substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
      nextAnimalIdNumber = 0;
      animals = new TreeMap<String, Animal>(animals);
   }

   /**
    * Returns a unique identifier, for an <tt>Animal</tt> object, based on the
    * zoo identifier and the field <tt>nextAnimalIdNumber</tt> which is incremented
    * ready for next time the method is called.
    *
    * @return a unique identifier.
    */
   public String allocateId()
   {
      // increment nextAnimalIdNumber and then construct a six digit string from it
      nextAnimalIdNumber++;
      String s = Integer.toString(nextAnimalIdNumber);
      while ( s.length()<6 )
        s = "0" + s;
      return zooId + "_" +  s;
   }

   /**
    * Adds an animal to the zoo.
    *
    * @param animal the Animal object to be added.
    */
   public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
   {
      animals.put(animal.getName(), animal);
   }

   /**
    * Reads <tt>Animal</tt> data from a text file and adds them to the zoo.  The
    * format of the data is specified in the MyZoo coursework assignment.
    *
    * @param animal the Animal object to be added.
    */
   public void readDataFromFile()
   {
      int noOfAnimalsRead = 0;

      // set up an owner for the FileDialog
      JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
      jframe.setVisible(true);
      // use a Filedialog to select a file to read from
      FileDialog fDialog = new FileDialog(jframe, "Read from", FileDialog.LOAD);
      fDialog.setFile("import001.txt");
      fDialog.setDirectory(".");
      fDialog.setVisible(true);
      String fname = fDialog.getFile();
      jframe.dispose();

       File inFile = new File(fname);

    String fileName = "import002.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;


        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  

        }

      addAnimal( new Animal("golden eagle", "Eddie", this) );               //
      addAnimal( new Animal("tiger", "Tommy", this) );            
      addAnimal( new Animal("lion", "Leo", this) );         
      addAnimal( new Animal("parrot", "Polly", this) );             
      addAnimal( new Animal("cobra", "Collin", this) );       

      noOfAnimalsRead = 5;                                       

      // this next line should be retained
      System.out.println("no of animals read from file was " + noOfAnimalsRead + "\n");
   }

   /**
    * Prints out details of all animal in the zoo.
    *
    */
   public void printAllAnimals()
   {

      System.out.println("\nDetails for all animals in Zoo " + zooId);
      System.out.println(  "==================================");

      Collection<Animal> c = animals.values();
    // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "import001.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;

        for(Object s: animals.keySet()) {

       // Yeah, I hate this too.
       String k = (String) s;

       // Now you can get the MailItems.  This is the part you were missing.
       List<Animal> listOfAnimals = animals.get(s);

       for(Animal animal: listOfAnimals) {
          System.out.println(animalItem.getSomething());
          }
        }
        }
    }
```

I currently cannot get my printAllAnimals() method to work as it should.

When executing the method printAllAnimals(), it does not do anything and wont, However it is supposed to use the Collection object c, so that animals stored in the zoo can easily be checked

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been trying to getting this working for hours and I am therefore  confused.

Comment: This is a very related question with the same problem on `printAllAnimals` method but seems that you posted it from other account or people in the same class do have the same problem (and probably the same implementation =\ ).

Comment: Hi, yes some other people in the same class as me are also having the same problem

Comment: It looks like you never use `c` at any point...

Comment: Please explain a) what `fileName` is for, b) why there are nested `for` loops in your method, c) why you create `c` and `k` but never use them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this code, the first thing I noticed is that your constructor uses the animals Map to initialize itself. Just initialize the map using an empty constructor. i.e.

```
animals = new TreeMap<String, Animal>();
```

Then call the method to read from the file which also fills your map.

```
readDataFromFile();
```

finally if you want to iterate over a map and display the contents, you will need to do something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Animal> animalEntry : animals.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(animalEntry.getKey() + "/" + ((Animal)animalEntry.getValue()).getName());
}
```

Comment: @ Alex Schultz                                                          Hi Finally got the code working, Thank you so much for your help, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @jacov, please mark the answer as correct if it helped you solve your problem so others can find/use this information as well. Thanks!